# Sort user defined objects with multiple constraints in a single stretch using java

Tags: java, sorting, multiple-conditions

I'm having employee objects and i want the sorted list by name in descending order and salary in ascending order.

```
 class Employee {

    String name;
    Long salary;
}
```

Comment: Can someone give me implemented code instead of some theoretical answers

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking for, you may want to implement `Comparable` interface in your class and then implement `compareTo()` method in the way you want it to behave when you want objects of your class to be sorted.

Another possibility is to create your own Comparator, but first option seems to be easier one in this case.

Comment: is there any implemented code? @Przemysław Moskal

Comment: @Pandiyan You need to write it on your own. As this question is already flagged as duplicate, I suggest you to take a look at that answer and look for further informations there.

Answer (score -1):

Easy: compare by name and then, if the previous comparing returns 0, compare by salary.